# MVC model value becomes null on post back

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting null value for the model on postback.I am not able to find out where I am going wrong.I have seen similar questions but couldn't find any solution yet.
Here is my code:

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult ContactUpdate(string id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        string[] testsplit = id.Split(',');
        List<int> intTest = new List<int>();
        foreach (string s in testsplit)
        intTest.Add(int.Parse(s));
        ObjectParameter ObjParam = new ObjectParameter("ErrorCode", 0);
        var cont = db.spErrorContactGet(365, ObjParam);
        var ToBeUpdated = (from contacts in cont
                           where intTest.Contains(contacts.ResponseID)
                           select contacts);
        IEnumerable<spErrorContactGet_Result> Update = ToBeUpdated.ToList();

          return View(Update);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactUpdate(List<spErrorContactGet_Result> Res)
    {

        if (Res == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

     //do something
    // redirect to another view
    }
```

Here is the model class:

```
public  class spErrorContactGet_Result
{
    public int ResponseID { get; set; }
    public string ContactAlchemyMessage { get; set; }
    public string ContactTeamAlchemyMessage { get; set; }
    public string ContactElectronicAddressAlchemyMessage { get; set; }
    public string ContactAccountAlchemyMessage { get; set; }
    public string CRMContactID { get; set; }
    public string InfluenceLevel { get; set; }
    public string JobRole { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string HonorablePrefix { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string ContactAuthPhoneId { get; set; }
    public string ContactAuthDmailId { get; set; }
    public string ContactAuthEmailId { get; set; }
    public string AllowFax { get; set; }
    public string PartnerContactAuthPhoneID { get; set; }
    public string PartnerContactAuthDmailID { get; set; }
    public string PartnerContactAuthEmailID { get; set; }
    public string PrivacyStatementReviewed { get; set; }
    public string PreferredLanguage { get; set; }
    public string IndWorkPhone { get; set; }
    public string FullNamePronunciation { get; set; }
    public string CRMOwner { get; set; }
    public string KeyContact { get; set; }
    public string MarketingAudience { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

}

I am unable to post the view in the right format.

Comment: cant say anything from the things you provided..try to insert view here

Comment: What is the model type on the View?  Is it the list, or a single instance of spErrorContactGet_Result?  Definitely need to see the view.

Comment: @Neel It isn't coming as razor/html.It would be great if anybody can tell me how to post the razor syntax here.

Comment: intracept: the model is a List of spErrorContactGet_Result.Inside the view I have a table showing rows of spErrorContactGet_Result items.I have used DisplayFor for the column title and I tried both EditorFor and TextBoxFor for the table data.The table is wrapped in a form using @Html.BeginForm and there is a submit button using which I intend to send the list back to the controller.

Comment: So this model class got auto generated when I added the spErrorContactGet in the .edmx.There is no declaration for this class in .Context.cs but the classes are defined under .context.tt .Is this any relevant to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that structure of your view differs from one that is of your model, they must syntactically match. If you would post your view it could help. BTW there is no 'Postback' in MVC

Comment: @LUIFA Using a submit button in a form we can hit the controller action with the [HttpPost] attribute where we can do operations on the recieved model rt.That is what I meant by postback.